# In Clojure, is there a function like Haskell's on?

Tags: haskell, clojure, functional-programming, combinators

In Haskell, we have [`Data.Function.on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on):

```haskell
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
(.*.) `on` f = \x y -> f x .*. f y
```

In Clojure, I want to be able to define, for example,
an anagram predicate as follows:

```clojure
(defn anagram? [word other-word]
  (and (not= word other-word)
       ((on = sort) word other-word)))
```

It's trivial to implement:

```clojure
(defn on [g f] (fn [x y] (g (f x) (f y))))
```

But is there any built-in function
that accomplishes the same goal?
I can't seem to find one.

Comment: maybe ` (defn on [g f] #(apply g (map f %&)))` in clojure's varargs-if-possible spirit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no built-in that does what you are looking for. If you are going to implement it, though, I think you can afford to be a little more generic, since Clojure has vararg support and lacks currying:

```
(defn on
  ([f g]
     (fn [x y]
       (f (g x)
          (g y))))
  ([f g & args]
     (on f #(apply g % args))))
```

This lets you write something like

```
(defn same-parity? [x y]
  ((on = mod 2) x y))
```

which of course is easy in Haskell too, as

```
sameParity :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Bool
sameParity = (==) `on` (`mod` 2)
```

But in Clojure the partial application of mod is a little trickier, so it's customary to provide equivalent functionality via &args if you can.

Comment: The varargs version of `on` rubs me the wrong way... Am I reading it correctly that `((on = mod 2) x y)` is equivalent to `(= (mod x 2) (mod y 2))`? I like the Haskell version fine, since (`mod` 2) is explicit about the order of the arguments, but in Clojure I would have expected `(mod 2 x)` not `(mod x 2)`.

Comment: @EricBailey Pasted an old version with a `(fn [x y])` missing, sorry. As for the varargs order, mine is definitely the order that fits with other partial-applying functions. Compare, eg, `(swap! x / 10)`: that's converted to `(swap! x #(/ % 10))`, not `(swap! x #(/ 10 %))`. It may look unnatural if you are used to haskell, but this order is useful much more often than the alternative.

Comment: On second thought, `(mod x 2)` makes more sense in Clojure, I just don't have any desire for the varargs version.

Comment: Either way, you've answered my question and given me some food for thought. Thanks!